# Google Maps SDK with Swift, myLocation can be nil

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps SDK for iOS and would like to know the user's current location. According to the documentation, the [myLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#a12191ce62bc53c8fd95c144f607311a5) property on [GMSMapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view) will return a nil value if no location is available:

> If My Location is enabled, reveals where the user location dot is
>   being drawn. If it is disabled, or it is enabled but no location data
>   is available, this will be nil.

However, when using Swift if it's not possible to check for nil as the field is declared as non-nil. Of course, if the field is nil at run time this means the app will crash.

[image: Google Maps SDK in XCode]

Does anyone know how to get around this? I would like to know if the location is not nil and, if not, use the value in my code.

Answer (score 1):

> it's not possible to check for nil

This is not correct. `myLocation` is an *implicitly unwrapped optional*, and those can be compared with `nil`, e.g.

```
let location = self.mapView.myLocation
if location != nil {
    // Use location ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this using Key Value Coding.

```
// Will *not* work as 'myLocation' declared as non-nil
if let location = self.mapView.myLocation {
    ...
}

// Works using KVO.
if let location = self.MapView.valueForKeyPath("myLocation") as? CLLocation {
    ...
}
```